# Get text from Web page

Tags: android

I want to get text from web,i wrote code,use indexOf and subString,but it don't work.

```
int index = response_str.indexOf("Remote IP Address:");
index += "Remote IP Address:".length();
index += "</div><br /><div id=\"value1\">".length();
int end = response_str.indexOf("</div><br /><br />", index);
String strIP = response_str.substring(index, end);      
Log.d("","Hello" + strIP  );
```

And this is sample text,i want to get **49.156.53.152**

```
<body>
<div id="title">Remote IP Address:</div><br /><div id="value1">**49.156.53.152**</div><br /><br />
<div id="title">UserAgent:</div><br /><div id="value2">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11</div><br /><br />
<!-- Everyone of CCorp employees, Good luck ! --><br />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the html page to a sting. and use regex / string operations to obtain the needed data

```
try {
                if(!url_text.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    textView.setText("");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.getText().toString());
                    // Get the response
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    String response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
                    textView.setText(response_str);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL String empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Some error occured.");
                textView.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
```

maybe the easiest way is to use sting.split function

```
String[] separated = response_str.split("**");
separated[0]; // part before the **
separated[1]; // your needed ip string
separated[2]; // part after the second **
```

Comment: This is get all text,i just want to get 49.156.53.152

Comment: its just a name for a sting array, it contains parts on which the html page is spitted into whit the string.split function

Answer (score 0):

You should try using this.

```
    myString = String.subString("<div id=\"value1\">", YOUR_ORIGINAL_STRING.len);
    String required = myString.endsWith("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_TO_HTML_PAGE).get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.getElementsByAttribute("value1");
String ip = newsHeadlines[0].text().split("**")[1];
```

The last line is based on Greezer post. I personally would replace it with a simple regex pattern that matches all possible IP adresses.

Something like:

`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`